# How to set the server name in an SSH welcome message

Tags: ssh, sshd

Each time I log in to my VPS, running I'm using OpenSSH, I can see the lines below in the MobaXterm SSH client:

```
Last login: Thu Jul 28 17:15:02 2016 from xxx
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
Linux vpsxxx.ovh.net 2.6.32-042stab111.12 #1 SMP Thu Sep 17 11:38:20 MSK 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

server    :
hostname  : vpsxxx.ovh.net
```

The `server` entry is empty. Is it possible to set a server name that would appear in this "welcome message"?

EDIT:

After reading the answers, here is what I came up with:

- I loaded an ASCII art file with my logo onto the server.
- I wrote a script that will trim `/etc/issue.net` and then `cat` the logo file as well as `echo` a few lines (legal warnings about unauthorized access and some server info – name and IP addresses).
- I added a cron job on an every minute (now daily) schedule to run that script and send its output to `/etc/issue.net`
- In `sshd_config`, I deactivated the MOTD (`PrintMotd no`) and activated the banner (`Banner /etc/issue.net`).
- I restarted the sshd service and all went fine.

It is to be noted that when "printing" the banner, sshd strips it of tabulations. Where `cat /etc/issue.net` shows correct formatting, the banner does not, which is a minor annoyance with which I can live.

Comment: [Possibly related](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100052/modify-the-ssh-welcome-message-to-include-system-ip-address)

Comment: That messaga is probably in `/etc/issue` or in `/etc/motd`. Edit there.

Comment: @Holloway: my question is indeed related to the one you're pointing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message is probably in `/etc/issue` or in `/etc/motd`. Edit there.

Comment: The exact text that I posted is indeed in `/etc/motd`. But editing it has a caveat: once I restarted the machine, I found out that the file had been reset to its initial contents. I'll follow the ideas given in [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163436/updating-motd-on-login) and add a cron job that writes everything I want in the motd. Once I'm done, I'll post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the /etc/issue.net file (where you'd write whatever you want to be displayed when connecting via SSH). Make sure you uncomment the `Banner /etc/issue.net`
in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and then restart openssh server.

Comment: Yes, this is a great possibility. When I searched the web before posting, I discovered in the Red Hat documentation for OpenSSH that the banner existed and could be set in `/etc/sshd_config`. I'll come to that in a few days. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be generated from the real hostname, which you can set up using (obviously) [`hostname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname) command:

```
hostname my-different-vpsxxx.ovh.net
```

Comment: the hostname is already being displayed :) What I needed was a "title" for the server. Thanks to NuTTyX's comment, I've modified it in `/etc/motd`.